# How to create filter for each tab?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to define a filter on a tabcontrol. When I switch tabs I would like the value to be different for each tab. I have created a directive for this:

```
app.directive('colorFilter', function($filter) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'tableFilter.html'
      };
});
```

How can I create a reusable filter for each tab with his own color?

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/82YBjepobHqLEa5163JC?p=preview

Comment: You want filter tab content by colorFilter?

Comment: I can't understand anything to your question. A filter is a function. It has an input, and an output. What is the input of your filter, and what is its expected output? Wht do you want to achieve? You said "When I switch tabs I would like the value to be different for each tab". The value of what?

Answer (score 0):

Done I just had to define a scope on the directive:

```
app.directive('colorFilter', function($filter) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          test: '=test'
        },
        templateUrl: 'tableFilter.html'
      };
});
```